# Getting Admin User in Formula

Tags: formula, user, user-admin

I currently have a formula field in an object, but it is grabbing the Admin email when I put `$User.email` in the field, even when I am not logged in as the admin. I am completely unsure why the admin is grabbed as the current user.

Comment: There's no restriction that "email" is unique among salesforce users. Perhaps you and the admin both have the same email address?

Comment: Why did you delete your old question and remove much of the detail?

Comment: @sfdcfox, how can i get the email of the current user that is logged in? Using the above notation when I am logged in it displays my email but when checked in a Heroku app it is grabbing the incorrect email.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, the now deleted question spoke more about the HTTP call; I have narrowed it down to just the field that is causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are running as a user with a different email? That merge field should always match `UserInfo.getUserEmail()`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, this displays the proper field, yet sends the admin email